# How to automatically validate after typing the input without using any frameworks, just simple code for my registration form?

Tags: html, css, validation, wamp

I want to know how to validate inputs after typing without using any frameworks or complicated code since this is only for my registration form?

Like some website after i type the email they automatically validate like the email is "already use" or email is "valid"

I'm using HTML and CSS for my front-end and PHP and WAMP for my back-end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use Javscript to validate your fields.  The better way is to post your data to a PHP script on your server.  This can be accomplished using javascript and a text field event, like onblur.  So when the user is done entering text into your text field, you post the data to your server.  A PHP script can then validate it by checking a database or whatever it needs to do.  You can then return a response to your javascript, indicating success or failure.  Look up AJAX calls.  You might be better off using jQuery, it's a bit easier than raw javascript.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using PHP to validate fields (or any other server-sided code) because it would be extremely inefficient. Unless you need to verify a field based on a database (such as the availability of an username), validate the fields with JavaScript and then with PHP (only once after form submission). Try to keep connections between the client and the server to a minimum.

Comment: @JCOC611: the only problem I have with client-side validation is that it's easily disabled/overcome.

Comment: Yeah that's why I suggested to recheck the data once the form has been submitted in the server-side. The difference with your approach is that the client only needs to connect to the server once after the form has been loaded (when it submits it).

Comment: @JCOC611: Well, he specifically mentioned that he wanted to be able to check something as soon as he's done typing it.

Comment: @AugustineFrendz: You don't want to check your e-mail against a database?  Or you don't want to do it with PHP?  PHP would be your only option unless you switched to another server-side scripting language that can connect to your database.

Comment: yes i want to check after typing it ^^ is there a easy/simple way of doing it? ^^

Comment: What I mean is that if you are going to check a field, such as name or last name, making sure that it exclusively contains letters, then to check that with PHP would be inefficient.

Comment: @AugustineFrendz Yes, it's in my answer.  You need to use javascript to post your form data to your PHP script in the onblur event of the input field.  Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6jgar/

Comment: @JCOC611 I understand that.  What **I'm** saying is that he needs to check with PHP to validate the e-mail address.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). It's actually quite simple code to implement, so hopefully it's just what you'll need.